# Unable to get data from elastic search SearchResponse

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve the data from SearchResponse class with the above code:

```
SearchHits searchHits = searchResponse.getHits();
for (SearchHit searchHit : searchHits) {
    SearchHitField title = searchHit.field("title");
    System.out.println(title.getValue().toString());
}
```

But I get a null pointer exception in title.getValue() function. The "title" field is definitely there and I can verify that by printing the search response which gives the following output:

```
{
  "took" : 13,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myTye",
      "_id" : "5c849b0f-d72d-4cc9-9b8c-e1201f888f94",
      "_score" : 2.4181843,
      "_source":{"esId":"100200153", "title":"Book 1"}
    }
}
```

I know that I can retrieve the data with searchHit.getSource() but I am wondering why the above solution isn't working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify `.fields(fields)` in the request to be able to access the `fields` part.

For example, if you have a query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

you get in the `hits` section of the result some fields (`_id`, `_type`..., `_source`).
But, if you have something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["my_field"]
}
```

you get back a different result:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_malformed",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "my_field": [
                  "whatever"
               ]
            }
         },
         ...
```

You notice there, in the `hits` you have `fields` where the field specified in the search request is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are almost there.  On each hit, instead of getting the title, get the _source object, then the title field from that source object.